# Applying a default theme to a Chart series

Tags: c#, xml, data-visualization, mschart

Using MSchart controls is somewhat difficult because of lack of information on the XML theme part.

I'm creating a chart programatically and dynamically and then adding a theme to it using a XML theme file.

I do not know how many series there will be but I'm trying to add one series for the total amount on each column in the StackedColumnBar.

So I create each serie in a foreach loop from the data and then add the Total series as a bubble chart type.

Now I have to apply a different series theme to the Total series and let all others have the same theme.

I tried naming the series "Total" in both chart and theme file. The real catch is the *Template*="All" attribute because this isn't documented anywhere so I have no idea how it all really works and how it's being applied.

Example of a theme:

```
<Chart BackColor="White"
      BorderWidth="2"
      Palette = "None"
      PaletteCustomColors="#F29E39; #007463; #E76E34; #A4A4A4; #94BBA3;"
      BorderlineDashStyle="Solid"
      AntiAliasing="All">
  <Series>
    <Series Name="Total"
        BorderWidth="0"
        LabelForeColor="#FF000000"
        LabelFormat="C"
        IsVisibleInLegend="false"
        IsValueShownAsLabel="true" >
    </Series>
    <Series _Template_="All"
            BorderWidth="0"
            LabelForeColor="#AAFFFFFF"
            LabelFormat="C"
            CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.9, DrawingStyle=LightToDark"
            IsValueShownAsLabel="false" >
    </Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea Name="Default"
              _Template_="All"
              BorderWidth="0">
      <AxisY IsInterlaced="true"
             InterlacedColor="#E8E7DC">
        <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
      </AxisY>
      <AxisX>
        <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
      </AxisX>
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Legends>
    <Legend _Template_="All"
            Alignment="Center"
            LegendItemOrder="ReversedSeriesOrder"
            Docking="Bottom"/>
  </Legends>
</Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we want to add Series for existing chart area its better to use databindXY in code behind, example:

```
var query = ... select new
{
sumXValue = ..,
sumYValue = ..
} //chart datasource

chart1.datasource = query;

Series series = new Series(); series.Name = "Total";
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
series.Points.DataBindXY(query, sumXvalue, query.sumYValue);
chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

this will adding new Series to existing Series in chartarea

Comment: Adding the Series has never been the problem. It's adding a specific template to a specific series in the XML that I do not know how to do.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, but why you use many template on one ChartArea, as far as i know,, only 1 template can be appliedd to 1 ChartArea,, unless your plan is using many ChartArea?

Comment: I was trying to make the last one a bubble with the total value floating above the stack. Is there perhaps another way I could do that?

Comment: did u try the last series with.. chart1.Series[chart1.Series.Count - 1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I came across while I was trying to solve the same problem recently. If you are using an XML template, you can just add a  element for each series in your data, even if you are adding the data at runtime, just make sure the order of the series matches how the data is added and it works without any issue. I have tested doing combination charts with this method and it works well.

```
<Series>
    <Series Name="FirstSeriesName" Borderwidth="0"></Series>
    <Series Name="SecondSeriesName" Borderwidth="0"></Series>
    <Series Name="ThirdSeriesName" Borderwidth="3"></Series>
</Series>
```

I haven't figured out how to combine this with the *Theme* option, but as of right now unfortunately it looks like you would have to style each series individually to use the XML theme (or change the options for the single series at runtime).